# Arrange widgets in layout

Tags: qt, layout, qt4, qt5

i want to achieve following layout behavior:

```
    | A  |  B  |       | A  |     |
 1) |---- -----|    2) |----   D  |
    | C  |  D  |       | C  |     |
```

Align A,B,C,D with each other and allow D to take available space if B is hidden.

I can achieve layout behaviors 1 or 2 with multiple ways. But i cannot seem to find solution to satisfy both of these conditions without removing widgets from layouts and re-adding later when B hides/shows with qt default layouts.

I tried so far:

1) grid layout - when B is hidden, D stays in place. Can align like i want if i will start to track hide-show status of widget B.

2) combinations of hbox and vbox layouts - D will get all space, after B is hidden, but when B is shown - A and B are never aligned. Once again i'll need to rearrange all widgets to achieve behavior i want.

I suppose Grid layout best suited for my purposes, but row span is set in stone when I add widgets.

Is there simple solution i miss?

Comment: `QGridLayout` + `QWidget::setSizePolicy()` are surely able to solve this (rather vanilla) use case. You should show your code if you expect somebody here to point out your problem: [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following code:

```
#include <QMainWindow>
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow, public Ui::MainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
};

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    setupUi(this);

    QWidget *left = new QWidget;
    QWidget *right = new QWidget;
    QHBoxLayout *hbox = new QHBoxLayout;
    QVBoxLayout *vboxLeft = new QVBoxLayout;
    QVBoxLayout *vboxRight = new QVBoxLayout;

    vboxLeft->addWidget(new QLabel("A"));
    vboxLeft->addWidget(new QLabel("C"));
    auto b = new QLabel("B");
    vboxRight->addWidget(b);
    vboxRight->addWidget(new QLabel("D"));

    left->setLayout(vboxLeft);
    right->setLayout(vboxRight);

    hbox->addWidget(left);
    hbox->addWidget(right);
    centralWidget()->setLayout(hbox);

    QAction *toggleB = new QAction("Toggle B");
    toggleB->setCheckable(true);
    connect(toggleB, &QAction::toggled, this, [=](bool toggled) {
        b->setHidden(toggled);
    });
    mainToolBar->addAction(toggleB);
}
```

You can toggle as many times as you want, it will keep the layout clean:
[image: toggle layout]

Comment: thanks for your reply, problem with this approach is that A and B are not really aligned - if A has different height then B - widgets would not look aligned. `vboxLeft` splits height between A and C and `vboxRight` does same for B and D.

Comment: Well, you problem is not explained clearly. What does it mean to have A aligned with B if they're not the same height, it doesn't make much sense. Because you also need to align A with C in the same time.

Comment: yeah, that's what i mean by saying that Grid layout suits best for my purposes. I need each row and column to resize to greatest width/height in a row/column. And if widget is hidden - to stretch that column for entire length